# Tibco BusinessWorks 6 module properties references

Tags: tibco-business-works

When you run a tibco project in local, which module properties does it refer at run time? The ones in the module (module properties) or the ones in the application (properties)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application properties. If you have another profile other than the default, the properties used are the profile defined by default.

Answer (score 0):

In runtime, application properties are ones that are being injected. Even if you run it in "local" application is deployed in default appSpace. Furthermore, you can define property profiles for different env's on the application level.

Please take a look for reference:

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.3.4/doc/html/GUID-3FDD406E-3602-4725-94A3-CBA962E3F40B.html